# Network not properly restored after VPN disconnect

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

This is a followup of my earlier question [Windows 7 can't connect to samba share on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/691235/windows-7-cant-connect-to-samba-share-on-linux), because I think I can phrase the question now in a more appropriate form.

I'm using a laptop running Windows 7 to connect to my company network using a VPN installed by the company. 
Now when I boot this computer, I can login to my Linux server SAMBA share by giving the user/password. However, when I connect to my company using VPN I can't reach my server anymore (which is expected and not the problem). The problem is, when I disconnect, it doesn't restore the machine to it's previous state and I still can not connect to my server anymore until I reboot.

Since the VPN was installed by my company I don't really know where to look at or what VPN vlient this is. Before we had Windows XP and there it worked, but I don't know if there is some new VPN involved or if it is the same.
So if somebody has an idea how I can fix this, I would appreciate it.

**update**

Output from `route print` after a reboot:

```
     Netzwerkziel    Netzwerkmaske          Gateway    Schnittstelle Metrik
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.250    192.168.1.103     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0   Auf Verbindung     192.168.1.103    281
    192.168.1.103  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung     192.168.1.103    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung     192.168.1.103    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung     192.168.1.103    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung     192.168.1.103    281
```

And this is the output when I connected to my company and disconnect afterwards:

```
     Netzwerkziel    Netzwerkmaske          Gateway    Schnittstelle Metrik
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.250    192.168.1.103     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0   Auf Verbindung     192.168.1.103    281
    192.168.1.103  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung     192.168.1.103    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung     192.168.1.103    281
   xxx.xxx.xxx.60  255.255.255.255    192.168.1.250    192.168.1.103     26
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung     192.168.1.103    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung     192.168.1.103    281
```

So the only difference is this line:

```
   xxx.xxx.xxx.60  255.255.255.255    192.168.1.250    192.168.1.103     26
```

where the IP points into my company.

**UPDATE2**

After some time, it seems this line disappears and this is what now is left, but it still doesn't work.

```
     Netzwerkziel    Netzwerkmaske          Gateway    Schnittstelle Metrik
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.250    192.168.1.103     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0   Auf Verbindung     192.168.1.103    281
    192.168.1.103  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung     192.168.1.103    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung     192.168.1.103    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung     192.168.1.103    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung     192.168.1.103    281
```

One thing I also noticed: When I connect to my box, before I connect to my company, then I can still connect after the disconnect. When I don't do this and try to connect afterwards, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: It simply means your routing table is not correctly reset. Please post the routing table before connecting to the VPN, and after disconnecting from it.

Comment: How can I extract the routing table?

Comment: @Devolus Run `route print` in a `cmd.exe`-prompt.

Comment: I updated my question with the output of `route` Apparently there is a difference. Now the question is how I can get rid o fit.

Comment: @Devolus You can also look at your `ipconfig /all` (before/during and after) to see if the wrong gateway/dns is left there. After that i think we really should now the VPN client. There are known VPN clients with problems after disconnect. Are you running the latest version etc... If it's not the standard Windows client you should see an icon in the systray (next to the time). What icon are you clicking to connect and the dialog that opens, can't you see in there what client it is?

Comment: Furthermore... after the disconnect, can you ping the ip of your linux server?

Comment: @Rik, the ping works, because when I go to the root of the server, I can see the offered samba shares. But it doesn't accept the login credentials. This seems more like a problem with a user/domain thing, than with the networking. As for the VPN, I click on the network indicator in the right lower corner (W7) and there I have a connection "VPN" which I can connect to, but I don't know to what service/programm it is associated to.

Comment: @Devolus Yep, if you can ping the ip, even ping the hostname, and see the server in the network and it asks for the login it's definitively not a network-problem. Then it all depends on the config of the SAMBA-server etc...

Comment: @Devolus Mmm, it could also be something like [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818088). Like that after connecting to a domain, Windows leaves something after disconnecting and you can't login locally. I take it you internet browsing works ok after disconnecting from VPN?

Comment: @Devolus Another thought. Is the company on the same subnet range as your local network (i.e. `192.168.1.x`). If so, i would change your local one to `192.168.88.x` or something. That way your shares won't disconnect when connecting to the VPN.